# Image fails to load after javascript redirect is triggered

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have an odd issue in Firefox. I have a aspx page that redirects the user to a particular URL based on a form post. The code behind mimics a shopping cart experience, so I have not found a way to remove this page entirely. The issue that I am having is that the image is displaying a broken image, even though it takes some time for the page to redirect. This is only happening in Firefox and Chrome. I also do not want to force the page to delay before the redirect, because I would like the user to redirect as soon as possible. Some times the page doesn't even show the redirect is so fast.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="proxy.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="proxy" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Walmart Mobile</title>
</head>
<body>
<div><img src="/img/interim-loader.gif" alt="loading" 
width="32" height="32" style="margin-bottom:7px;"/>
<br/>Processing...</div>
<script language="JavaScript">
    if (location.replace) location.replace("<%= redirectURL %>");
    else location = "<%= redirectURL %>";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Update - the img code below worked well.

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,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" alt="loading" width="32" height="32" style="margin-bottom:7px;" />
```

Comment: if you remove the script tag the image loads fine?

Comment: If you remove the redirect the image loads as expected. I believe the redirect is causing FireFox to stop the image load, but I am hoping it is something else.

Comment: Is the image hosted on http and the page on https? Some browsers block insecure content on secure pages by default. Actually, nvm. I think @MikeMcCaughan is on the right track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the question, it seems like you want to show an image without waiting for the image to load -- a tough nut to crack, but not impossible.

You could use a [data: uri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), which makes it so that the browser doesn't need to load anything from the network. See also [Ian Hixie's data: URI kitchen](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/data/data) for help in generating them.

Otherwise, you will have to put in a pause, at least until the browser has finished loading the image.

Comment: No problem. One thing I should point out for completeness' sake is that if that image is an animated GIF, Firefox (at least) will stop the animation while the page redirects... I have found no way around that particular weirdness.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I did noticed that, but this works well enough.